# Elasticsearch conflict during reindex with opType Create

Tags: elasticsearch, reindex, version-conflict-engine-exception

I've used reindex API with opType=create and I've expected for conflicts to be impossible because only new records will be inserted. But I get conflict message. Whats wrong? Does elasticsearch has timegap between checking if document exists and inserting it during reindex (not using some kind of CAS)?  Does it mean if I set conflicts to `proceed` I'll get expected behavior to insert only absent documents? Or do I need to implement client side locking\mutex stuff?

The error I get in tasks:

```json
{
  "completed": true,
  "task": {
    "node": "xxx",
    "id": 63525604,
    "type": "transport",
    "action": "indices:data/write/reindex",
    "status": {
      "total": 1101727,
      "updated": 0,
      "created": 240999,
      "deleted": 0,
      "batches": 241,
      "version_conflicts": 1,
      "noops": 0,
      "retries": {
        "bulk": 0,
        "search": 0
      },
      "throttled_millis": 479999,
      "requests_per_second": 500,
      "throttled_until_millis": 0
    },
    "description": "reindex from [xxx] to [xxx][_doc]",
    "start_time_in_millis": 1696388661522,
    "running_time_in_nanos": 554683695369,
    "cancellable": true,
    "cancelled": false,
    "headers": {}
  },
  "response": {
    "took": 554678,
    "timed_out": false,
    "total": 1101727,
    "updated": 0,
    "created": 240999,
    "deleted": 0,
    "batches": 241,
    "version_conflicts": 1,
    "noops": 0,
    "retries": {
      "bulk": 0,
      "search": 0
    },
    "throttled": "7.9m",
    "throttled_millis": 479999,
    "requests_per_second": 500,
    "throttled_until": "0s",
    "throttled_until_millis": 0,
    "failures": [
      {
        "index": "xxx",
        "type": "_doc",
        "id": "xxx",
        "cause": {
          "type": "version_conflict_engine_exception",
          "reason": "[xxx]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [3])",
          "index_uuid": "xxx",
          "shard": "0",
          "index": "xxx"
        },
        "status": 409
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of elasticsearch is this? Are you reindexing into an empty index? Does the target index have the same schema as the source index? Are you doing any additional processing during reindexing? Is your source index getting updates during reindexing process? Are you using custom routine or parent/child documents in the source index?

Comment: @imotov
versio 7.16.2

Comment: @imotov to index which can have some records, but mostly empty with bit different schema with no additional processing. New index can get updates during process.  No custom routine or child documents

Comment: Are you trying to reindex multiple indices into one index? Can you please share the reindex API?

Comment: So what you are saying it is totally possible that the target index can have a record with the same id as a record in the source index.

Comment: I'm moving data from index with old mapping to index with new mapping while both indexes gets same update events from third party source